# why i cant remove the object with override

Tags: java

In the collection test, I create a class named Name and override the equals method, like following,

```
class Name implements Comparable<Name>{
private String firstName, lastName;

Name(String firstName, String lastName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName(){
    return lastName;
}

public String toString(){
    return firstName + " "+lastName;
}

public boolean equals(Name name){
    return firstName.equals(name.firstName) && lastName.equals(name.lastName);
}

public int hashCode(){
    return firstName.hashCode();
}
```

But When I test the remove() function in collection, it was false and the Name("Andy","Light") is still in the collection. What is the wrong with my code?

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Collection c = new HashSet();
    c.add("hello");
    c.add(new Name("Andy","Light"));
    c.add(new Integer(100));
    c.remove("hello");
    c.remove(new Integer(100));
    System.out.println(c.remove(new Name("Andy","Light")));
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Comment: so you mean i need override the lastName hashcode()?

Comment: You also need to add a `compareTo` method because you are implementing `Comparable<Name>`

Answer (score 3):

There is a comment and an answer that says your `hashCode()` method is not consistent with `equals()` because you didn't include `lastName` in the hash code calculation. They are both wrong.

The `hashCode()` implementation is allowed to use a subset of the values used by `equals()`. It will cause more hashcode collisions that way, offsetting improved speed of `hashCode()` vs degraded performance of hash-buckets. A subset hashcode may be ok, it depends on likelihood of `Name` objects having same `firstName`.

Your *problem* is that the signature of `equals()` is wrong. It *has* to be `boolean equals(Object)`.

`boolean equals(Name)` is *not* an override of `boolean equals(Object)`, so you didn't actually override/implement the `equals()` method, and as such ended up with `hashCode()` being *inconsistent* with `equals()` *(but not for the reason the others said)*.

If you add the `@Override` annotation, the compiler would have caught this problem. Always use the annotation.

Change to:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (! (obj instanceOf Name))
        return false;
    Name that = (Name)obj;
    return this.firstName.equals(that.firstName) && this.lastName.equals(that.lastName);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return this.firstName.hashCode();
}
```

This of course assumes that neither can be null.

---

As @MickMnemonic says in a comment:

> It's considered bad practice to leave out fields that are included in `equals()`

To include `lastName` in the calculation, use [`Objects.hash()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash-java.lang.Object...-):

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(this.firstName, this.lastName);
}
```

---

Also, as @StephenB [said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416972/why-i-cant-remove-the-object-with-override/38417039#comment64241134_38416972):

> You also need to add a `compareTo` method because you are implementing `Comparable<Name>`.

Here you use `Name` as a parameter, not `Object`, because of the generic type argument to `Comparable`.

Example (if sorting by first name before last name):

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Name that) {
    int cmp = this.firstName.compareTo(that.firstName);
    if (cmp == 0)
        cmp = this.lastName.compareTo(that.lastName);
    return cmp;
}
```

That implements a firstName/lastName [lexicographical ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). You may want to use [`compareToIgnoreCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) or maybe a [`Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) for correct localized ordering.

Comment: Correct, and good catch. However, it's considered bad practice to leave out fields that are included in `equals()`, from the calculation of `hashCode()`, so I would add `lastName` in there (and use `Objects.hash(...)`).

Comment: thanks. I've removed my answer, because editing it wouldn't have added enough value vs. your answer.

Comment: "This of course assumes that neither can be null." is an unsafe assumption because the class does not defend against `null` values.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to use generic in this class, how could I override the equals() method? I mean I don't want to use "instanceOf"

Comment: @Alice You can't implement `equals()` without using `instanceOf`.